# Is it possible that a function can return 2 or more values with different data types in php?

Tags: php, parameters, return-value, type-conversion, return-type

```
//sample Pseudo Code
function djikstra($source, $destination){
   //after some computations....
   return $distance_taken, $path;
}
```

`$distance_taken` is an integer and `$path` is an array.

Comment: return as an array

Comment: Return `array` or `object` or  `json`

Comment: You can return an array or standard object or json

Comment: `return [$distance_taken, $path];`

Comment: Kindly please show me some snippets?

Comment: Can an array contain many data types like: $this_array[0]= *an interger AND $this_array[1]= *an array ?

Comment: Yes array is a collection of values of any datatype!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return more than one value. But you can return an array:

```
function djikstra($source, $destination){
   //after some computations....
   return [$distance_taken, $path];
}
```

So when you call this function, you can make use of `list` to get the values:

```
list($distance_taken, $path) = djikstra($source, $destination);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... Let me try this.

Comment: Now that was awesome! Thanks I owe you a lot! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can just return one or no value

```
return array('distance_token' => $distance_taken, 'path' => $path);
```

Then access them by

```
$result = djikstra($source, $destination);
$distance_taken = $result['distance_token'];
$path = $result['path'];
```

Comment: Did you tried this one?

Comment: yeah， It works!

Answer (score 1):

A function always return one type. You can use an array if your variables are the same type.

But The best way to do that is to create an Object

```
<?php

class DikjstraObj {

  var $source;
  var $destination;

  function __construct($source, $destination) {
    $this->source = $source;
    $this->destination = $destination;
  }

}

// ///////////////

// in your function simply do 
function djikstra($source, $destination){

  //after some computations....
  $dObj = new DikjstraObj($source, $destination);

  return $dObj ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array`

```
return array('distance_taken' => $distance_taken, 'path' => $path);
```

Use `JSON`

```
return json_encode(array('distance_taken' => $distance_taken, 'path' => $path));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't basically but you can create a class. 
PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as we can't go without reference, I put an answer too, and summarize the others goods ones:

## Reference way (AKA `C` pointer like)

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) can be used when you want to directly work with the variable without making a temp copy and returning a new value to erase the old one. This is the way C language work, and can improve performance for big variable manipulation.

To use reference, you just have to put a `&` before the `$` of your function parameters:

```
<?
function djikstra(&$source, &$destination){
    //after some computations....
    $source = 'new val 1';
    $destination = 'new val 2';

        // return can be omited or used to handle & return error 
    return ; 
}

    // init
$source = 'default val 1';
$destination = 'default val 2';

    // will change the val on the fly
djikstra($source, $destination);

    // will print "new val 1 - new val 2"
echo $source. ' - ' .$destination;
```

---

Other goods ways :

## Array()

As said by @Thamilan, this is probably the most common way.

> You can't return more than one value. But you can return an array:
>
> ```
> function djikstra($source, $destination){
>    //after some computations....
>    return [$distance_taken, $path]; 
>    // or `return array($distance_taken, $path)`
> }
> ```
>
> So when you call this function, you can make use of `list` to get the
>   values:
>
> ```
> list($distance_taken, $path) = djikstra($source, $destination);
> ```

**Nb: careful with [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php), it's a tricky function to use, read the doc**

## Object

The @Topsy is a good way too if you already code in Oriented Object style, as you'll have to apply function to full object and expect the full modified object back.

**Avoid this and go for #1 or #2 if you work in procedural.**

> A function always return one type. You can use an array if your
>   variables are the same type.
>
> But The best way to do that is to create an Object
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> class DikjstraObj {
>
>   var $source;
>   var $destination;
>
>   function __construct($source, $destination) {
>     $this->source = $source;
>     $this->destination = $destination;
>   }
>
> }
>
> // ///////////////
>
> // in your function simply do 
> function djikstra($source, $destination){
>
>   //after some computations....
>   $dObj = new DikjstraObj($source, $destination);
>
>   return $dObj ;
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks @Blag this will help